# while uploading image getting cocoa 3840 error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, nsmutabledictionary, nsjsonserialization

Here i am trying to sent image to server side but its giving me error

```
    if(picking)
            {
                NSLog(@"entering in to image side");
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"content-Disposition:form-data;name=\"pic\"\r\n\r\n filename=imageName.jpg\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:picking]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            }

            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [request setHTTPBody:body];
            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[body length]];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

                if([data length]>0 && connectionError==nil)
                {
                    NSError *error;


                    NSMutableDictionary *jsonResponse=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

                    if(error){
                        [Utitlity alertFunction:@"Warning" message:[error localizedDescription]];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        [self requestComplete:jsonResponse];
                    }
                }
```

this image present in sign up screen,if i didn't select picture in sign up screen means ,customer registration getting success.while select image its give cocoa 3048 error.

Comment: [Search on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+cocoa+error+3840). Do any of those help?

Comment: @rmaddy i had over come those problem ,can u help me i am struggle in problem while uploading image..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in your below statement. Per Apple documentation `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option should be used for arrays and dictionaries. Please try with `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments`.

```
NSMutableDictionary *jsonResponse=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

> Constants NSJSONReadingMutableContainers Specifies that arrays and
>   dictionaries are created as mutable objects.
>
> Available in iOS 5.0 and later. NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves Specifies
>   that leaf strings in the JSON object graph are created as instances of
>   NSMutableString.
>
> Available in iOS 5.0 and later. NSJSONReadingAllowFragments Specifies
>   that the parser should allow top-level objects that are not an
>   instance of NSArray or NSDictionary.
>
> Available in iOS 5.0 and later.